# Sum of Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

If two functions are Riemann integrable then their sum is also Riemann integrable, but I guess the converse of the statement is not true, i.e., if the sum is Riemann integrable, then the individual functions may not be Riemann integrable. I am in search of such two functions. Any hints please.

Answer (score 3):

An uninteresting example: $f=\chi_{\bf{Q}}$ on $[0,1]$ and $g=-f$.